# Size of ArrayList is 0 after adding items to it

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist, android-adapter

I declared an `ArrayList` in a class and initiate it when I start the Async task; then I add items in the `doInBackGround()` method, but after that, when I send the array-list to the constructor of an adapter, the size of the array-list is still 0.

I really have no idea what I am doing wrong.  Help please.

Here is my code:

```
public class FindNewThingFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private PullRefreshLayout pullRefreshLayout;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<ThingsItem> arrayList;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_found_new_thing,container,false);
    listView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.things_item_list_view);
    progressBar=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.things_item_progress_bar);
    new LoadDongxiData().execute();
    ThingsItemListViewAdapter adapter=new ThingsItemListViewAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

private class LoadDongxiData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    public LoadDongxiData(){
        arrayList=new ArrayList<ThingsItem>();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            doSomething();
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){}
                arrayList.add(new ThingsItem(itemImageUrl, itemName, price, userIconUrl, userName, userComment, numberOfLikes, numberOfAddDouToList, numberOfReply, userHomePageLink, itemDetailLink));
            }
        }

    }
}


}
```

Comment: try add item to list in onPostExecute and also set adapter there.

Comment: Are you sure you set it to the adapter *after*? The background task has probably not yet completed.

Comment: @Thilo just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExecute()`? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follows:

```
public class FindNewThingFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private PullRefreshLayout pullRefreshLayout;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<ThingsItem> arrayList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_found_new_thing,container,false);
        listView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.things_item_list_view);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.things_item_progress_bar);
        new LoadDongxiData().execute();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    private class LoadDongxiData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        public LoadDongxiData(){
            arrayList=new ArrayList<ThingsItem>();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            doSomething();
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                arrayList.add(new ThingsItem(itemImageUrl, itemName, price, userIconUrl, userName, userComment, numberOfLikes, numberOfAddDouToList, numberOfReply, userHomePageLink, itemDetailLink));
            } 
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            if(arrayList != null && arrayList.size() > 0) {
                ThingsItemListViewAdapter adapter=new ThingsItemListViewAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe also make `arrayList` a private field of the task.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){}
```

Is this empty loop intentional or is this where you were trying to add the items? From the way you have your braces indented, it seems like it wasn't intentional. If this was intended as a time delay, counting from 1 to 10 will take less than a fraction of a second.

After having set the data, just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExecute()`.

You can set your adapter in `onCreate()`. Just don't forget to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` every time the underlying data for your adapter changes. You will need to make your `adapter` a 'global' variable, though.

Answer (score 0):

Set your adapter in `onPostExecute` of your `Asynctask`

Answer (score 0):

Note that you AsyncTask will run in background. while its running in background the UI thread will proceed to next line of your code means before

```
new LoadDongxiData().execute();
```

this lines finishes it execution next line will be called. so the arraylist size is still 0.

The Solution is You Should have this lines after LoadDongxiData() finishes it execution.

```
ThingsItemListViewAdapter adapter=new ThingsItemListViewAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

call these lines after onPostExecute() method of LoadDongxiData.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move add item to list and set adapter code in onPostExecute :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
   super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
       arrayList.add(new ThingsItem(itemImageUrl, itemName, price, userIconUrl, userName, userComment, numberOfLikes, numberOfAddDouToList, numberOfReply, userHomePageLink, itemDetailLink));
   }
   ThingsItemListViewAdapter adapter=new ThingsItemListViewAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your doInBackground() method...

```
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            doSomething();
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                arrayList.add(new ThingsItem(itemImageUrl, itemName, price, userIconUrl, userName, userComment, numberOfLikes, numberOfAddDouToList, numberOfReply, userHomePageLink, itemDetailLink));

              }
            }
        }
```